# Problem with compare date now with date from MySQL [Angular]

Tags: mysql, angular, date

I try to compare date from MySQL:DATENOW and compare it with date now in angular.

This is my function

```
  getReports(onSuccessCallback: Function) {
    this.http.getReports(Globals.userID).subscribe(data => {
      data.map((report) => {
        const nowDay = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        report.deadLine = new Date(report.deadLine).toLocaleDateString();
        if (report.deadLine === nowDay) {
          console.log(true);
        }
      });
      onSuccessCallback(data);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

When i do this is work fine and take whats equal and console true, but the problem is whan i try to console true if Date already passed
I try:

```
if (report.deadLine < nowDay){
          console.log(true);
        }
```

and its not work

Comment: Convert both to unix timestamps and than you compare numbers?

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have To Change The Code Set

```
  const nowDay = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
            report.deadLine = new Date(report.deadLine).toLocaleDateString();
           if (report.deadLine < nowDay){
          console.log(true);
        }
```

To This

```
 const nowDay = new Date();
        report.deadLine = new Date(report.deadLine);
        if (report.deadLine < nowDay){
          console.log(true);
        }
```